# Filter duplicate values from dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular

**I have a ColumnDef:**

```
  relatedToolsColumns: ColumnDef[] = [
  { field: 'toolId', name: 'Tool Number', type: 'dropdown', optionsList: this.tools, optionsListField: 'id', optionsListName: 'toolNo', width: '70%' },
  {
     field: 'delete', name: 'Delete', type: 'icon-button', width: '30%', sortingDisabled: true, icon: 'delete',
     callback: this.deleteRelatedTool.bind(this)
  }];
```

**I am subscribing the tools with the endpoint call 'getGageNoList':**

```
 ngOnInit() {
  this.tool = this.data.tool;
  this.readonly = this.data.readonly;

 
  this.tprecmApiService.getGageNoList()
     .subscribe((val) => {
        this.tools = val;
        this.relatedToolsColumns
           .find((column: ColumnDef) => column.field === 'toolId')
           .optionsList = this.tools;
     });
  }
```

**This is what i have for tools:**
[tool Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcvlG.png)

**This is what i have in the UI for Tool display which currently have two identical tool number chosen from the dropdown list.**
[The UI Add tool Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQveG.png)

**The Dropdown list of tools:**
[The dropdown list of tools in the grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5N88j.png)

**I need to filter these dropdown to only ones that are not getting displayed on the grid already.**

Comment: var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  x.remove(x.selectedIndex);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.tools.filter((tool, index, arr) => arr.findIndex(t => t.toolNo === tool.toolNo) === index)`

will give you an array where the ones that have the same toolNo as one before them filtered out because findIndex returns the first item that matches the function.

Answer (score -1):

with some small js you can filter them

```
if (!(dropdownTool in toolsArray)) { ... } // push to array you send to HTTML to loop in
```